# concatenate values of 2 vars and create a new var in mule 4

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-esb

How can i concatenate 2 vars in mule 4 & create a 3rd var?

I have tried concat(vars.a , vars.b) but dint work.

```
<set-variable value="concat(vars.a , vars.b)" doc:name="c" doc:id="b6782bbc-868f-42d7-556a-bd1f94dadf466" variableName="c"/>
```

Also i tried

```
<set-variable value="#[vars.a + vars.b]" doc:name="c" doc:id="b5455272bbc-868f-34-556a-bd1f94dadf466" variableName="c"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Mule 4, we can concatenate variables using '++' instead of '+'

This is analogous to the Concat operation mentioned on Mulesoft blog at 
[Dataweave operator for concat](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/dataweave-operators#concat)

I have used the above link to successfully concatenate two variables as follows:

```
<set-variable value="#[vars.a ++ vars.b]" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="8a9fc576-38fe-44f6-90e1-4d8054c10fb0" variableName="c"/>
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: That link is for Mule 3, DataWeave 1.0, here is the relevant Mule 4 DataWeave 2.0 link: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule4-user-guide/v/4.1/dw-core-functions-plusplus

Comment: Vars.a contains a number & Vars.b contains an object. It threw error if i use ++. How can i convert to String before applying ++. I tried as vars.a as :string ++ vars.b as :string but that dint work

Comment: You need parenthesis to control the order of evaluation: `(vars.a as :string) ++ (vars.b as :string)`

Comment: I tried using vars.a as :string . I got this error  input " as :", expected PropertyName, Function Call

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in a comment that vars.a is a number and vars.b contains an object. Concatenating a string. It doesn't make sense to concatenate a string to an object. You should extract some string from the object first.
Also note than in Mule 4 types have different names than Mule 3 starting with uppercase.

Example:

```
vars.a as String ++ vars.b.age as String ++ vars.b.name
```